# How to load an ontology into Fuseki from a remote RDF/XML or OWL file?

Tags: rdf, jena, owl, ontology, fuseki

I have an ontology in OWL or RDF/XML format, say Dublin Core Terms, for example, but online and **not locally**.

To load it into Fuseki via the Web interface, I use the following query:

```
CLEAR GRAPH <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>; 
LOAD <http://dublincore.org/2012/06/14/dcelements.rdf> INTO GRAPH <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>;
```

Here is a screenshot of my interface (I have changed the endpoint to /update as this is a modification operation).

[image: spinning]

The problem is that the interface simply hangs (spinner spinning forever) and does not conclude the operation.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried your example and it works for me with the current latest Fuseki. Check the server logs to see if the request was received (the server logs start with a POST log entry). What storage choice are you using for the data?